# Why is null not an object in Java, if it can be assigned to any reference type?

Tags: java

My first question is does the null literal have a reference type? I am confused on if null has no reference type, or the null literal does have a data type, but there is no name for it. Either way as a literal, null can be of any reference type. If null can be assigned to any Object type, why can null not be an object itself? Even a String literal is an object itself in Java. Every reference type is able to make an Object in Java, then should not the same be applied to null?

Comment: "If null can be assigned to any Object type" => maybe you are confused about the difference between variables and objects? Variables are not objects; variables are *references* to objects. You can set any variable to `null`, which is a special value that means "this variable refers to no object". `null` is a special *reference* value.

Comment: I agree it **isn't**, but it seems to me that null **could be** (or could have been, in an alternate Java universe) an actual object.  I interpret the OP as asking about why the language is the way it is.

Comment: @user13784117 There's a design pattern called the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) but it seems to me that lisapizza is confused about what `null` is exactly, and that this pattern isn't really relevant to her confusion.

Comment: @Jesper I used the term Object loosely, I understand that the variable is not technically the object but a reference to it, but a lot of people just end up loosely referring to the variable as an object later on just for easiness. String literals without being assigned to an variable will be an object if you check with instanceof operator, curious to why the same treatment is not for nulls. I know that null is just a literal value that can be assigned to any reference type, but why not allow null to be an Object or have its own data type if its being assigned to any reference data type.

Comment: What difference would having a special null object or having a special type for null make? If it doesn't provide anything, then why add these features?

Comment: See [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415/144918) -- Stack Overflow's scope is limited to *practical* questions about *problems you actually face* -- ones whose answers change the way you practice software development, and which solve a specific problem that you wouldn't know how to solve without that answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unfortunately, in many tutorials, books and other resources about Java, the terms "object" and "variable" are used in a sloppy way, which can lead to confusion similar to what you describe in your question.

For example, look at this line of code:

```
String message = "Hello World";
```

People will often say "I have a `String` object named `message` here with the value `"Hello World`". This is wrong and it makes beginners think that objects and variables are the same thing, and that objects have names.

Accurate would be: "I have a variable named `message` here which is a reference to a `String` object with the value `"Hello World"`.

Variables and objects are not the same thing. A variable* is not an object, it's a *reference* to an object (it's a pointer to an object somewhere in memory).

Variables have names. In the code above, there is a variable named `message`. Objects do not have names.

There is also not a one-to-one correspondence between variables and objects. Multiple variables may refer to the same object.

The value `null` is a special value that you can assign to variables* that means "this variable refers to no object". It's just like a null pointer in languages such as C and C++.

It doesn't really make sense to talk about `null` being an object. It's not an object, it's a special reference value to make variables refer to "no object".

> If null can be assigned to any Object type

This is why I suspect you're confused about the difference between objects and variables: you do not assign `null` to an object, but to a **variable** (of "any object type" which is the same as "of a non-primitive type").

*: we're talking about variables of non-primitive types here

For a more advanced understanding:

The value `null` has a bit of a [bad reputation](https://hackernoon.com/null-the-billion-dollar-mistake-8t5z32d6) (it's the cause of many bugs). You might want to use [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) to help prevent some of the problems that `null` causes.

See also the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern), which is a design pattern about the idea of having a special object that represents "the empty value". This might be useful in special situations.

Comment: if a String literal such as "Car" is an object alone, why not the same for null literal though? I understand that variables are not objects but references to the objects in the heap, I should have been more clear, sorry about that.

Comment: @lisapizza Because `null` is a special reference which means "refers to no object". What object would you want the "no object" reference want to point to, and what use would it be?

Comment: @lisapizza In the line `String vehicle = "Car";` you can think of the `"Car"` literal as short for `new String( "Car" )`, making an object in memory (likely in heap, but that is an irrelevant implementation detail), and returning the number of the address in memory where that object can be found. That number is then assigned as the value of the variable `vehicle`. To clear out `vehicle` we would assign a special value as a flag, like `-1`, to indicate “not currently assigned to any object”. For security & simplicity, Java hides the memory address from us, and `null` does the job of -1 flag.

Comment: @BasilBourque `String vehicle = "Car";` says 'see that `"Car"` literal? please create an object with that value in a special place in memory, and assign it to `vehicle`'. I don't think the OP is confused about how `null`s *currently* work in Java. What they're asking is *why* wasn't Java designed so that the exact same thing happens with `String` constants and `null`s *instead*

Comment: To address the last paragraphs: arguably, the problem isn't null itself, but the poor language support for it.  Look for example at [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) for how nulls can be handled perfectly safely, efficiently, expressively, and concisely, without needing other objects.

Comment: @gidds the mistake is making the type of `null` be a subtype of all types, which *is* a problem will `null` itself (as implemented in Java)

Comment: As an analogy:  "Ross" is the *name* of the *person sitting at this keyboard*. "Mike" is the *name* of the *person who is Ross's boss*. "Nobody" is sitting at the kitchen table.

In this analogy, "person" = object, "name" = variable, "Nobody" = null.  "Nobody" does not refer to any person.  You wouldn't say "Nobody" is a person. It's what you say when there is *no person there at all*.

Answer (score 5):

Null *could* have been defined to be a unique `Object` with behavior very similar to `null` references. It could be a singleton with a unique name and otherwise uninstantiable; it could compare equal to itself with `==` and unequal to other non-`null` objects; it could have a unique class, say `Null`.

This is, in fact, a common design pattern known as the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).

So why isn't it that way?

- An `Object` variable can refer to an object of any class. But it doesn't work the other way around. You can't stuff an `Object` into any variable you like. I can't write:

  ```
  String str = new Object();
  ```

  Null objects would still require special language support. If `null` were a singleton object of class `Object` or class `Null` you could assign it to an `Object` variable, sure, but you wouldn't be able to assign it to a `String` or `ArrayList` variable. Java would require different type safety rules, making an exception for this null object so it could be assigned to any type.
- The null object pattern is typically class-specific. You make a null object for a specific class and then implement sensible behavior for that class's methods on the null object. For example, you could create a "null" list that behaves like an empty list, returning no elements when iterated over and returning a size of `0` when queried.

  That wouldn't work with a generic null object. A null object of class `Object` or class `Null` wouldn't have implementations of the methods available on arbitrary subclasses. If `null` were an object, what would happen if you called `null.open("...")` on a `File` reference or `null.start()` on a `Thread`? Those methods wouldn't be defined.

  Again, there'd have to be special language support. Maybe those calls could return `null` themselves? (What if they return `void`, though?) Or maybe they could throw `NullObjectException`s?

  At some point you're just reinventing null references.
- Finally, the simplest answer is: it's not that way because it's another way. Null could be a reference that points nowhere, or it could be a reference to a null object. Even if both were equally good solutions it can't be both. You're asking why it's "A" instead of "B". If it were "B", somebody would be asking why it's not "A".

Answer (score 3):

The easy answer is "because it isn't defined that way in the language".

Conceptually, the distinction is "null is a special Object" versus "null is no object".

Given the special treatment of null, for example, `null.equals("something")` will throw an exception, which is not true for `someObject.equals(null)`, I'd say the latter view -- null is no object -- is more coherent.

Comment: I'd argue that "null is a special Object that throws a NullPointerException when you try to do anything with it " and "null is no object" is basically arbitrary. You wouldn't be able to tell the difference in code.

Comment: Sure, but you've just invented the concept "special object", which I would object (!) to on the grounds of Occam's Razor.

Comment: @JoachimSauer "null is a special Object that throws a NullPointerException when you try to do anything with it" requires all other classes that take an object without calling any of its methods to implement the behaviour.

Comment: @OrangeDog how so? if you pass `null` to something that doesn't use it, it doesn't throw.

Answer (score 1):

It could be. In the same way that `Object` is a supertype of all (non primitive) types, `Null` could be a subtype of all types, with a single instance `null`.

`Null` would have every possible method, which would all throw `NullReferenceException` when called, and every possible field, which would also throw when accessed.

In the end, it would be indistinguishable from the current situation.